# Error in installing optional package qiskit-aqua[cvx]

Tags: python

I have been trying to use qiskit SVM and it needs the optional package qiskit[cvx]. While installing the package as

```
pip install qiskit-aqua[cvx]
```

I am encountering the following errors

```
>  running build_ext   building '_cvxcore' extension   error: Microsoft
> Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++
> Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/  
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxpy   Building wheel for ecos (setup.py) ... error  
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> 'E:\DevelopmentEnvironments\Anaconda3\envs\qiskit_env\python.exe' -u
> -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AMITAVA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mon8de59\\ecos_5ec689fff8044fcebbc759d1411788bb\\setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AMITAVA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mon8de59\\ecos_5ec689fff8044fcebbc759d1411788bb\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d
> 'C:\Users\AMITAVA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gknwgiii'
>        cwd: C:\Users\AMITAVA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mon8de59\ecos_5ec689fff8044fcebbc759d1411788bb\
```

I have wheels in my environment already as specified in [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9734/installing-qiskit-error-building-wheel-failed).
I have also installed the latest Ms Visual Studio Tools.

Python configuration is Anaconda, python version is 3.8.3

Comment: This seems to be less a problem with Qiskit rather than with cvx and your C++ version. Maybe try looking explicitly for the MS Visual C++ error, such as here https://github.com/benfred/implicit/issues/76 or here (see also the comments): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136595/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-require.html

Comment: yes, acc to the link I hv installed the build tools, rebooted - still the same.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on stackoverflow

Comment: I followed the conda instructions from this link --> https://www.cvxpy.org/install/ and it worked. I only did the step to install VisualStudio build tools for Python 3 and the "conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy" step since I was already working in the conda environment that I wanted. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem can be found here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua

I encountered same problem but I got it fixed while following the guide on the github page.

Give it a try

Comment: It should not be necessary to follow a link to learn the answer you propose. Please edit this post and include the entire solution here. Leave the link for attribution or further research, but not for the actual answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1131658)